# How to randomly render products after get API to obtain data in Vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

```
this.$http.get(api).then(response => {     
        vm.products = response.data.products; 
      });
```

If i have data about products and i want to randomly render products what should i do?

Comment: can you clarify what his means? you want to only show one randomly? you want to show a random assortment? you want to show them all but in a random order? additionally, some attempt that you made so far to render would be helpful in providing us direction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set a computed property where you shuffle your products list, something like this:

```js
computed {
  shufflesProducts() {
    return vm.products.sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5);
  }
}
```